# Soft keyboard covers all the window even with adjustPan

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I have a problem with my SearchActivity. It has a SearchView made with ActionBarSherlock .
when I click on the eyeglass in landscape orientation I have the softkeyboard to cover all the screen. But with adjustPan parameter I would expect to see the SearchView.

```
      <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarCompat" 
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        >
     </activity>
```

Do you know how could I see the SearchView while typing ? Or maybe I simple don't understand what adjustPan should do.

Thanks